# Nested =IF() formula in Excel almost working....but there's 1 value that doesn't have the expected output

Tags: excel, if-statement, nested-if

It works for every timepoint except for 96 hr - it returns the value of "6" instead of "96". I am quite sure it has to do with the fact that "6" is also in there, I just have no idea how to fix it.

`=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("WK-1",F306)),"-7",IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Pre",F306)),"0",IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("0.5",F306)),"0.5",IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("2 hr",F306)),"2",IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("6 hr",F306)),"6",IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("24 hr",F306)),"24",IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("48 hr",F306)),"48",IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("96 hr",F306)),"96",IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("168 hr",F306)),"168","1")))))))))`

Comment: Can you explain what the formula is supposed to do? I get the feeling there may be a simpler way to accomplish whatever it is you want to do

Comment: Try swapping the nesting locations for `6 hr` and `96 hr` `IF()` statements.

Comment: Yes sorry- we have a column of data that reads with stuff like "D1: 2 Hr EOI" or "D2: 168 Hr EOI", "D1: EOI", "D176: EOI" etc etc. The Day 1, 2, etc is a separate column and I have that worked out. The numeric value of the hour, when one exists, needs to be extracted into an "hour" column. Pre is always 0, EOI is always 1, then when defined the hour value needs to be pulled out-just the integer. I put in the SEARCH because there's extra information besides the 6 hr etc in the cell that has the hr.

Comment: Numbers should not have `""` around them, other wise they are stored as text and not numbers.

Comment: And as @bugdrown has stated you need to test the longest strings first.  Reverse the order of the IFs.

Comment: I didn't realize that. I'll reverse the order real quick and see if that helps.

Comment: Reversing the order to have the longest strings first did the trick. Thanks.

Comment: I would be looking at a list and use vlookup() - much easier, imho, to control.